# Is there a way to make the left tag start counting from the right side of an object?

Tags: html, css

So I'm making an app and I have an image and some text with the users name and last name but when the name is a bit longer the images goes over the name and after some digging in the CSS its because the left tag is starting to count from the left side of the name making it so when the name is a bit longer it moves me image. You probably didn't understand anything so I'll attach some images to explain my problem.

**What I need:**
[image]

**What I have if I make the name larger:**
[image]

**My code:**

```css
body{
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
}

.center{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.text-center{
    text-align: center;
}

.btn{
    -webkit-appearance: button;
    -moz-appearance: button;
    appearance: button;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.off{
    display: none;
}

.error{
    color: var(--red);
    margin-left: 0.5em;
}

.navbar {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: var(--white);
  margin-top: 0.5em;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: var(--black);
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.navbar-left {
  margin-left: 20%;
}

.navbar-left img {
  margin-top: 0.4em;
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
}

.navbar-centered {
  float: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.navbar-right {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 0em;
  margin-right: 20%;
  max-height: 65px !important;
}

.navbar-right .btn {
  background-color: var(--white);
  border: 2px solid var(--red);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 8px;
  color: var(--red);
}

.logged-in {
  margin-top: 0.1em;
  margin-right: 3.5em;
}

.logged-in ul {
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  padding-right: 1em;
  padding-left: 1em;
}

.profile-a-img {
  padding: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  position: relative;
  top: -2.5em;
  right: -10.2em;
}

.logged-in img {
  border-radius: 10em;
  max-width: 3em;
}

.name-id {
  list-style: none !important;
}

.name-id .ID {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  top: -1em;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  padding-right: 1em;
  font-size: 15px !important;
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/navbar/dashboard_style.css') }}">
<div class="header-div">
  <div class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-left">
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-centered">
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-right">
      <div class="not-logged-in off">
        <a href="{{ url_for('login.loginpage')}}">Log In</a>
        <a class="btn" href="">Registration</a>
      </div>
      <div class="logged-in">
        <ul class="name-id">
          <li><a class="name" href="">Antonio Goncalves</a></li>
          <li><a class="ID" href="">ID 1</a></li>
        </ul>
        <a class="profile-a-img" href=""><img src="https://sunrift.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/Blake-profile-photo-square.jpg" alt=""></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Name, ID and image are loaded from DB so I really need this to be universal.

If you have any suggestions on how I can make this work please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% sure what you are trying to achieve, but it sounds like you want to use `transform: translateX(-100%);`. This will have your element moved to the left by its full width.

Also consider getting rid of every `!important` you can - this should not used regularly.

Comment: After posting the question I started messing around and I managed to make it work using translate. But thanks any way.